# Accessing items in fetched data

Tags: javascript, fetch

I fetched some data using google search places API. I am able to access items in the returned data array except for the link in the photo attributions. I used the following method, which works for all the other data elements:

this.data.name, this.data.vicinity, this.data.icon etc but this.data.photos.html_attributions returns as undefined.  What am I doing wrong? Please see the images below for the data structure.  Thx as you assist.

[image: top-level structure]
[image: need to access html_attributions node element]

Comment: Hi @Obisi7 if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `this.data` is an array. You should access the array by index:

for example:

```
let firstItemName = this.data[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0].photos[0].html_attributions[0]
```

If you need the link then you might need to parse the `href` from `<a ..`

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to access that data

Answer (score -1):

You have to put in the array index, for example:

```
let var1 = this.data[0].photos[0].html_attributions[0];
let var2 = this.data[1].photos[0].html_attributions[0];
let var3 = this.data[2].photos[0].html_attributions[0];
...
```

Comment: Again, I am able to retrieve the other data e.g. this.data.name, this.data.icon, etc without any error.  The only issue is with getting the html_attributions that is a node element in photos array. I have also tried your suggestion but got error: "Cannot read property photos of undefined"

Comment: That's an oddly worded error... it's been too long since I worked with javascript to know what exactly that means.  It sounds like it has a problem accessing the photos array.  Do you get an error if you try to set something to `this.data[0].photos` ?

Comment: It just doesn't like this.data[0] reference.  As I indicated, when I use this.data.name or this.data.icon (per the structure), I get the correct data with indicating the element index. But when it comes to photos which itself is an array, I can't get its array element (html_attributions) using ...photos[0] or straight ...photos.html_attributions.  Strange.  I have written a working regex to parse the <a href correctly.

Comment: Weird.  Have you tried accessing it with something like `photos.firstChild`? or `element.firstElementChild`